# Disable mod_pagespeed for specific IP

Tags: mod-pagespeed

We would like to disable mod_pagespeed for our office as it can make administering image based content on sites frustrating no knowing which is the current version of an image.

Does anyone know a way of disabling it for a specific IP ?

I am aware of the url switch ?ModPagespeed=off however need something that does not require user intervention every time. Also i know the cache can be cleared on the command line but users adminstering content will not have this level off access.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Apache 2.4, this needs to go into the virtualhost directory context (inside `<Directory /var/www></Directory>`:

```
<If "-R '89.101.196.98'">
    #ModPagespeedDisableFilters combine_css,combine_javascript
    Modpagespeed off
</If>
```

You can disable the entire module or just specific filters only, which is useful to see how much it would "optimize" the images, or cause problems with javascript.